# Reading the body of SMIME encrypted email

Tags: outlook-addin, mapi

I have an Outlook addin which handles outgoing emails using the ItemSend event. as part of the handling I read the body and attachments of the outgoing email. 
when the user encrypts the email message (SMIME) in one environment my addin cannot read the body of the email - PR_BODY_W property (I assume that the body is in the smime.p7m). However, in a different environment my addin does find and read the PR_BODY_W successfully.

I wonder if my capability to to read the PR_BODY_W depends on whether the ItemSend callback is called before or after Outlook encrypts the message? is this configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook always represents signed and encrypted message as regular IPM.Note items. Even MailItem.MAPIOBJECT is a fake IMessage object.

How do you retrieve PR_BODY?

Comment: using   mapiObject->OpenProperty(
                PR_BODY_W,
                (LPIID)&IID_IStream,
                STGM_READ,
                0,
                &readStream); I also noticed that when I use Outlook Object Model to retrieve the body (instead of MAPI) it works in all environemnts